# Как переписать curl запрос в js?

Tags: javascript, curl

Добрый день, сделал API для загрузки файла и туплю как его вызвать из браузера правильно.

запрос curl'om выглядит так.

```
curl -X "POST" -d "audio_message_form[file]=C:\\fakepath\\Screenshot_2016-05-26_16-30-37.png&audio_message_form[chatId]=123123" -H "Accept:\ application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token:\ 123" test.loc/api/v1/audios.json
```

А как его переписать на JS я не знаю

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**-X, --request**

- (-X POST) Указывает метод пользовательского запроса для использования
  при обмене данными с сервером `HTTP`

**-d, --data**

- Отправляет указанные данные в запросе `POST` на `HTTP` сервер , таким же
  образом, что и браузер, как если бы пользователь заполнил HTML-форму
  и нажал бы кнопку отправки. Это заставит завиток передать данные на
  сервер с помощью заголовка content-type
  application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Сравните с  `-F`, `--form`.

**-H, --header**

- Дополнительный заголовок включает в запрос при отправке HTTP на
  сервер. Вы можете указать любое количество дополнительных заголовков.

И после всего этого через пробел указывается url.Поподробнее можно почитать здесь
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Приведу пример на Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.loc/api/v1/audios.json',
    headers: {
        "X-Auth-Token":'123',
        "Accept":" application/json"
    },
    data: "audio_message_form[file]=C:\\fakepath\\Screenshot_2016-05-26_16-30-37.png&audio_message_form[chatId]=123123",
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

AJAX На чистом javascript смотреть [Основы XMLHttpRequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest)